# Why do many churches use grape juice in communion?

Tags: communion, baptist

Some Baptists and many other evangelicals use grape juice in communion. Is this explained on any catechism (or systematic theology available online) ?

Does the reason for not using wine have to do with keeping oneself pure or the moral problems with alcohol?

Comment: Change "Baptists" to some Christian churches. I believe this is more of a congregational rule thing. The United Church of Christ (UCC) congregation that I attended some months ago in May used grape juice (very sweet!) and leavened bread (very puffy!).

Comment: I have some ignorance on the matter, hence my question. But isn't the split here largely between evangelicals and mainlines?

Comment: I have heard before that grape juice is unfermented (alluding to the purity) *and* the moral problems with alcohol-induced behaviors.

Comment: @pterandon No. I think you might not quite understand what the difference between mainline and evangelical means. It has to do with the beliefs of an individual or a group, not necessarily an entire denomination. Rules for communion are set at the denominational level. Every denomination has it's own rules for it's own reasons.

Comment: It may be as simple as the priest knowing there is people in his church with alcohol dependency issues and not wanting to needlessly tempt them.

Answer (score 25):

The Protestant practice of traditionally substituting grape juice for wine during *[communion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucharist)* must largely be credited to one man - [Thomas Bramwell Welch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bramwell_Welch)

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine#Christianity):

> While some Christians consider the use of wine from the grape as
>   essential for the validity of the sacrament, many Protestants also
>   allow (or require) pasteurized grape juice as a substitute. Wine was
>   used in Eucharistic rites by ***all Protestant groups*** until an
>   alternative arose in the late 19th century. Methodist dentist and
>   prohibitionist **Thomas Bramwell Welch** applied new **pasteurization
>   techniques** to stop the ***natural* fermentation process** of grape juice.
>   Some Christians who were part of the growing **temperance movement**
>   pressed for a **switch from wine to grape juice**, and the substitution
>   **spread quickly** over much of the United States, as well as to other
>   countries to a lesser degree. There remains an ongoing debate between
>   some American Protestant denominations as to whether wine can and
>   should be used for the Eucharist or allowed as an ordinary beverage,
>   with Catholics and some mainline Protestants allowing wine drinking in
>   moderation, and some conservative Protestant groups opposing
>   consumption of alcohol altogether. (*emphasis added*)

Anyone with basic knowledge of wine making knows that once grape juice is successfully squeezed and collected, it doesn't remain as juice for very long. Unpasteurized grape juice, if not consumed within a few days of harvest, will quickly ferment, rendering it not consumable (unless treated and stored to begin the wine making process).

As the excerpt from Wikipedia above states, prior to the turn of the 20th century "grape juice communion" was practically non-existent. Before the modern discovery of the pasteurization process, it would have taken a significant amount of effort to have enough freshly squeezed juice for a congregation readily available every Sunday (or less frequently depending on the denomination).

[image]

So, contrary to the traditional presuppositions held by Temperance Movement grandchildren, the theological "roots" of sipping grape juice instead of wine during communion has more to do with [pasteurization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasteurization#History) and [prohibition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prohibition_in_the_United_States#Winemaking_during_Prohibition) than it does biblical exegesis.

Comment: Can't I say really understand the reason for the photo, but it's a good answer otherwise :)

Comment: @Flimzy Wait a minute...you've never seen Lucy make grape juice before? :)

Comment: The wikipedia article failed to mention that Dr. Welch was also working on his own translation of the New Testament, of  which only the following fragment survives (John 2:10):  *Every man at the beginning doth set forth good grape juice; and when men have well drunk, then that which is worse: but thou hast kept the good grape juice until now.*

Comment: @guest37, do you have a reference for that quotation?

Answer (score 15):

The United Methodist Church is a denomination that uses grape juice instead of wine. I am using them as an example because their reason is explicitly stated in the Book of Worship:

> Although the historic and ecumenical Christian practice has been to use wine, the use of unfermented grape juice by The United Methodist Church and its predecessors since the late nineteenth century expresses pastoral concern for recovering alcoholics, enables the participation of children and youth, and supports the church's witness of abstinence.

The Book of Discipline also asks ordained clergy to abstain from alcohol in solidarity with recovering alcoholics.

Sometimes within the United Methodist Church people will try to teach that the wine of the day wasn't alcoholic or that the wine used by Jesus wasn't alcoholic. There is no absolute, verifiable evidence, biblical or otherwise, for this view.

Comment: This is what is what I have alway heard growing up Church of God. Mainly, if you are an alcoholic, just a small amount can be a trigger and not as much that any consumption is and of itself is necessarily a sin. Better to be careful. 1 Corinthians 8:9 "Be careful, however, that the exercise of your rights does not become a stumbling block to the weak."

Comment: At least in the US, the government provides an exemption to churches that allow minors to consume wine during the sacraments. This isn't illegal and so everyone can participate.

Answer (score 6):

All Protestant churches that use grape juice instead of wine will attempt to show that it is either biblical to forgo wine or not unbiblical to do so; biblical, meaning that the terms "cup of wine", "wine", in the Bible do not necessarily mean the fermented wine, according to them. Once they state this proposition, they add that alcohol has the tendency to cause immorality and therefore is unnecessary for use in the Lord's Supper/Communion.

Critics will point out that the majority of Protestant churches that forgo the use of wine historically (20th century) supported Prohibition and also used wine prior to the Temperance movement. Baptists are notable for this turn around. Read more about this phenomenon [here](http://www.brucesabin.com/alcohol.html).

So critics would call it political while those Protestants would call it biblical.

Answer (score 4):

I grew up in a small Methodist congregation in Europe. We used wine in communion when I was young. But then at one time we had a new visitor who never joined us in communion. Asked why, he told us that he is a dry alcoholic. One sip of wine would be enough for him to fall back in to the hell of alcoholism. So the council of our congregation decided to switch to juice just to leave no one behind. We did not use wine anymore from that day onward.

This particular friend became a member and is, as far as I know, still in the congregation to this day.

You see, we didn't need to have a . . . biblical reason, if I may say so, for using grape juice. We only wanted to include everybody who wants to join us. That's all.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing. If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Answer (score 2):

At least one good reason is because there are children in the congregation, and to make communion something that not everyone can participate in is contrary to the principles of the gospel.

Comment: At least in the US, the government provides an exemption to churches that allow minors to consume wine during the sacraments. This isn't illegal and so everyone can participate.

Comment: In the Eastern Orthodox Church, infants are communed as soon as they are baptized - with wine (although it is only a spoonful).

Answer (score 1):

It will vary by church. In my non-denominational church, we use grape juice and the pastor had simply stated “they used fermented grape juice in the Bible but we use unfermented because it’s just easier that way,” which I’m pretty sure is his nondescript way of saying, “we have a lot of alcoholics in recovery in this church”.

Comment: @Larry R Herrin . There’s nothing wrong with being a teetotaler but to say Jesus was as well is contradictory to scripture. He drank wine on many occasions, He even turned water to wine as His first public miracle. It is also worth mentioning they didn’t have all this bottling and refrigeration we have now, and fermenting was a way to increase the shelf life. So good for you for being abstaining from alcohol, that’s a great idea, but it is very dangerous to change scripture to make it match your own beliefs.

Answer (score 0):

Growing up in the Lutheran church, wine was always used.  White grape juice was provided as an alternative to those who had an alcohol addiction.  Wine is mentioned in the bible not grape juice... and drunkenness is a sin not the actual drinking of wine.  Man has injected their own perception into the words of the Bible and have made it fit their own opinions and desires.

I believe the practice of grape juice instead of wine is the product of the temperance movement and those who have injected fear and their own opinion to the Bible.  God doesn't inspire his words to be written in a diluted confusing manner.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Here's a bit of well meaning advice: if part of your answer could be copied into every answer you write then it doesn't belong in any answer! It is inappropriate to talk at length about people adding to the Bible, especially when it does not directly address this specific question. Instead, you should assume that people are trying to read an interpret the Bible faithfully and reasonably. I have edited out the parts of your answer that let it down.

Answer (score -1):

This is a complex issue that cannot be adequately discussed in this forum. The most definitive work on this subject is a book called Biblical Wines by Timothy and Liza Murphy. They covered the subject matter better than anyone I have read. They are linguists in Hebrew, Greek, and Latin, as well as, many modern languages. The book is an actual study that covers the entire Bible, front to back. Chapter 7 is very fascinating because it really digs into the issue of wine verses grape juice for Communion. It is very clear that God did mandate the use of various things for His worship and many people have clouded that fact with bad translations and serious misunderstandings of what the Word of God says. I would refer all to the Biblical Wines eBook before coming to any conclusions on this subject. God bless.
Check out this link from [Biblical Wines](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/517862).

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing, but instead of pointing us to an external resource, we'd much prefer that you quote and summarize the relevant parts here.  That way the content of the answer is always available.  I hope you'll improve this answer by editing it, and that you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: It is a difficult argument to claim that a self-published eBook with no scholarly references serves as the "definitive work" on this topic.

Answer (score -2):

My thoughts on a preference for grape juice are many. (1) I am a teetotaler as Jesus appears to have been as well as John the Baptist. (2) It was important to have unleavened bread, thus it makes sense to have "unleavened" juice for the same reason. Even the finest wines have dead yeast and dregs. Yeast represents sin. The blood and body of Jesus would have no sin. That of course is represented by the "wine" and unleavened bread. Ancient wine would have been full of dregs and bitter. I am convinced that the disciples must have used grape juice to provide the purity require in remembrance of him. Of course, this is speculation, and maybe wishful thinking but the disadvantages of wine far out-number the advantages. Insobriety is sinful, and drinking alcoholic beverages is entering into temptation. God does not tempt. I honor his keeping me from temptation. If I was to taste wine, then I could longer say that I am not imbiber. They accused Jesus of that. Perhaps they would me as well.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).

For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Comment: And Jesus turned water into Wine at the wedding feast!

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This is a good first answer, but the site favors substantiated answers and references over personal opinion.  Stack Exchange sites are Q&A sites, not discussion forums.  The OP specifically tagged his question "baptist."  Therefore, the ideal answer would provide an answer reflecting the official teachings of Baptist congregations and conventions.  Thanks!

Answer (score -6):

### Seventh Day Adventist Perspective

As Seventh Day Adventists, we believe it is the same reason why unleavened bread was used. Bread was a symbol of Christ, and leaven was a symbol of sin or corruption (as it is a bacteria). Jesus never saw corruption. In the same way, fermented wine is wine(the fruit of the vine, aka grape juice) after it has been fermented or corrupted. The blood of Jesus cannot be symbolized with corrupted wine.

In the Bible, both fermented and unfermented wine (grape juice) is referred to as wine. You must look at the context to figure out whether it's talking about fermented or unfermented wine.

EXAMPLES of fermented wine:

> Woe to him who gives drink to his neighbors,
>       pouring it from the wineskin till they are drunk,
>       so that he can gaze on their naked bodies!
>
> Habakkuk 2:15
>
> Look not thou upon the wine when it is red, when it giveth his colour
>   in the cup, when it moveth itself aright.
>
> At the last it biteth like a serpent, and stingeth like an adder.
>
> Proverbs 23:31-32

EXAMPLES of unfermented wine:

> The sceptre shall not depart from Judah, nor a lawgiver from between
>   his feet, until Shiloh come; and unto him shall the gathering of the
>   people be.
>
> Binding his foal unto the vine, and his ass's colt unto the choice
>   vine; he washed his garments in wine, and his clothes in the blood of
>   grapes
>
> Genesis 49:10-11

Definitely unfermented as the wine is being squeezed from the grapes.

> And gladness is taken away, and joy out of the plentiful field; and in
>   the vineyards there shall be no singing, neither shall there be
>   shouting: the treaders shall tread out no wine in their presses; I
>   have made their vintage shouting to cease.
>
> Isaiah 16:10

Same here. Unfermented as the wine is pressed from the fruit of the vine(grapes).

EDIT:
EXAMPLES WITHIN THE CONTEXT OF THE LAST SUPPER

Seeing as the Bible refers to wine as both fermented and unfermented, which was used at the last Supper?

> Matthew 26:27-29
>
> Then he took a cup, and when he had given thanks, he gave it to them,
>   saying, “Drink from it, all of you. This is my blood of the
>   covenant, which is poured out for many for the forgiveness of sins. 
>   I tell you, I will not drink from this **fruit of the vine** from now on
>   until that day when I drink it **new** with you in my Father’s kingdom.”

Both "fruit of the vine" and "new" are descriptions of unfermented wine, and are not descriptions of fermented wine.

> Mark 14:23-25
>
> And he took the cup, and when he had given thanks, he gave it to them:
>   and they all drank of it. And he said unto them, This is **my blood** of
>   the new testament, which is shed for many. Verily I say unto you, I
>   will drink no more of **the fruit of the vine**, until that day that I
>   drink it **new** in the kingdom of God.

Once again in Mark, Jesus makes the same mention of the fruit of the vine, and new. Luke mentions the same. There is more Biblical proof that this is unfermented, new wine (plain grape juice) than fermented. If anyone feels any different, I challenge you to show me Biblical proof that fermented wine was used in the last supper. You will find there is no Biblical support for this kind of thinking, only traditions of men.

Just ask yourself this. Why would God denounce the use of fermented wine in one part of the Bible, but allow His own Son to drink this? Isn't this inconsistent?

For more information on this, here are some great articles:

1. [Why I Don't Drink Alcohol](http://www.adventistworld.org/article/635/resources/english/issue-2009-1010/why-i-don-t-drink-alcohol)
2. [Christian & Alcohol](http://www.amazingfacts.org/news-and-features/inside-report/id/331/christian-alcohol.aspx)

EDIT:

Seeing as how this got negative votes, I am revisiting this answer, though I really cannot see why the votes were negative. From the Biblical perspective, it is clear that there are two types of wine. GOD AND HIS WORD DO NOT CONTRADICT. However, from the texts it may seem as if they do. Jesus was completely pure, the lambs that were slain, that were symbolic of His death, were supposed to be unblemished. How then can we say that Jesus partook of this substance that has gone through the process of putrefaction? More importantly, why would Jesus say that this substance symbolizes His blood? Let us try to reason without prejudice. Does this make sense?

It is clear that Jesus refers to untainted, pure wine, or grape juice as we call it today.

Now many made claims that, historically, this was impossible because there were no methods of preservation. This is false. There were many methods of preserving food and drink in Bible times, including grapes and unfermented wine. Some of these methods include boiling, filtration, cold storage, and sulphur fumigation. Dr. Samuele Bacchiocchi, in his book "Wine in the Bible - A Biblical Study on the Use of Alcoholic Beverages" explains many of these processes. Chapter 4 deals with a very in-depth study on the subject of the preservation of grape juice. I have included a link to Chapter 4 [here](https://www.biblicalperspectives.com/books/wine_in_the_bible/3.html).

My answer aimed to answer the question from a Biblical perspective, nevertheless, here is the counter argument for anyone that claims that there was no way to preserve unfermented wine beyond the season.

Comment: `blood of Jesus cannot be symbolized with corrupted wine` According to whom? The unleavened bread concept goes back to the passover celebration, when leaven was not allowed in the home during passover. There was no such rule regarding wine--if there had been, Jesus would not have used wine at the last supper (which was also a passover meal).  So this line of reasoning I find to be rather incredible. But if it's accepted by some specific church group, that should be stated in the answer.

Comment: There's actually a question about wine at the last supper here: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4322/was-the-wine-in-the-last-supper-fermented

Comment: @Flimzy “This is my blood of the covenant, which is poured out for many,” he said to them. “Truly I tell you, I will not drink again from the fruit of the vine until that day when I drink it new in the kingdom of God.” Mark 14:24 This is Jesus talking. Notice how he says the fruit of the vine, and also until I drink it NEW. Now are you really going to tell me this refers to corrupted wine which is arguably not the fruit of the vine anymore, and it is most DEFINITELY not new?

Comment: Jesus was perfect in everything, he NEVER drank corrupted wine, as this would go against scripture which time and time again talks about the evil of fermented wine. "Woe to him who gives drink to his neighbors..." Habakkuk 2:15 And are you really trying to defend a substance which has time and time again destroyed families, relationships, and lives? There is nothing good about fermented wine and my LORD had nothing to do with it. If you still think so, prove to me from the Bible that this is talking about fermented wine.

Comment: @jlaverde: You're still making a jump. This concept of "corrupt wine" is not found in scripture. I'm not saying there aren't groups who hold this view--I would just like you to tell me who they are.

Comment: @jlaverde: Sex has also destroyed families, relationships, and lives. So has money. So I'm assuming you've sworn to live a life of celibacy and poverty?

Comment: @Flimzy Wrong. Sex OUTSIDE of marriage has destroyed families, relationships, and lives. This is why God has prohibited it. The LOVE of money has caused these things and it's why Jesus denounced it. Sex and money are a blessing from God in the right context, when they have not been corrupted. It is EXACTLY the same for wine. When it is used contrary to how God wanted it to be used, it becomes a curse. And it IS found in Scripture! Or do people become DRUNK with grape juice? Do they act out of character and get naked by drinking grape juice? Think about the context for one second, brother.

Comment: Also I don't understand why I'm being voted down. Because my answer doesn't agree with your opinion or you beliefs? It answers the question and is backed up by Scripture. Come on people, I thought this was a "schorlarly" website. At least comment on WHY I'm being voted down.

Comment: @jlaverde: You're being voted down because your answer doesn't cite any official resources. It is, as written, only your opinion. And I would say, as I already have, that it is *not* backed up by scripture. There is no scripture I've ever seen that even mentions "corrupt wine," let alone defines in in the context of the Last Supper. The verses you do mention don't seem to have any relation to the subject at hand, except that some of them mention wine.

Comment: Read [this post](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/20) for ideas on how to improve your answer.

Comment: @Flimzy I have cited the Bible. There is nothing more official than that. My opinion is backed by Scripture, if you don't think so then you have not read my answer. I have edited my answer to include specific Last Supper examples where it tells about the NEW wine. The other verses are included to show that the Bible has two opposing views on wine. Because the Bible DOES NOT CONFLICT against itself as it is the Word of God, this MUST mean that it is talking about 2 DIFFERENT types of wine. By the context you can see when it is talking about unfermented wine or fermented wine.

Comment: @jlaverde clearly the bible is not authoritative in this matter. As you've shown there is clear debate and it is subject to interpretation. Most of the debate (at least that I've seen) is based on speculation and is unfounded. What you need to make this a *good* answer worthy of upvotes is to point to an actual scholar or theologian who agrees with the interpetations you've made here. Otherwise they appear to be inconsistent with both what we know about history and mainstream interpretations of scripture.

Comment: @waxeagle Hello brother. I believe you have hit upon a most important point. To me the Bible IS authoritative in all matters of life, this one included. The Bible is not open to private interpretation. God says and you either do or don't do. Many people interpret homosexuality as something that the Bible does not condemn, yet the Bible CLEARLY does. Some people interpret drinking wine as something that is not prohibited by the Bible, yet I have cited examples where it clearly says not to even look at it! There is a difference between deferring interpretations and disobedience to the Word.

Comment: I would continue but it will do no good. I will pursue this no further.

Comment: @jlaverde the question is not exactly whether the Bible is authoritative though. You're putting forth *your interpretation* as authoritative with no indication of your credentials, no reference to show your interpretation is consistent with any existing doctrine. Why should I believe this interpretation over the traditional one? Specifically when the traditional interpretation fits the historical context better than this one does.

Comment: Understood. I will add external references.

Comment: @waxeagle I have edited my answer and included external references.

Comment: @jlaverde I hate to be a stickler, but could you make those relevant to the points your making? It's good to link things, but rather than just linking them, tell us *why* they're important and *how* they support the argument you're making. Think about how you'd write a research paper, would you just dump your sources at the end? or would you work them in quoting and backing up your thesis with the ideas from the articles? that's what we're ultimately looking for here :). One of the things they *don't* tell you about SE is that it's partly intended to make you a better writer.

Comment: There is more to this than biblical context, The grape harvest season, the lack of pasturization techniques, the common use of fermented wine as drink in ancient cultures, The availablily of Fresh Grape juice on Easter Sunday when it is not the harvest season. The availablility of Wetche's Grape juice and the local grocery in todays society clouds the perceptions of many in todays modern world concerning the wine in the bible.  It's important to step back into history.  I believe there is more to answering this question than what is offered here.

Comment: @waxeagle this is simply further reading for those who wish an to read an honest in-depth study on this subject, because there is limited space here. I wished to shine light on the Biblical perspective, so as far as that, my answer is sufficient without these quotes.

Comment: @Marc If you believe your comment to be true, and I assume you do, please read the edit and the link provided in it. Let me know what you think of this reading.

Comment: I checked your link out. I'm sorry, I undestand that you believe it, but the Jewish people who know thier faith and traditions disagree with your link.  Wine was not grape juice.  Wine is discribed in scriptures as to "bring joy to God and man"  The fact that at Passover grape juice is given to children has nothing to do with the Jewish faith,the libations or the festivals where wine is very important and a treasured part of jewish heritage and culture and history.The link is not a large fabrication,but an wishful presumption to support an unbiblical unrealistic practice in a seperated Church.

Comment: @Marc Just because it is part of the culture, does not make it what God meant. Where in the Torah are you quoting this from? The wine that gladdens the heart is the pure one from the fruit, as is everything else that it speaks about in the passage. I'm not sure how far you read in the chapter, but one of the quotations was from Josephus. The Jewish historian from the 1st century. Culture and traditions may disagree, however the Word of God and historical accounts are in complete agreement. There is nothing good about the alcoholic beverage. Men beat their wives and children because of it.

Comment: @Marc It is a vile drink that is used in every pagan religion and in all worldly places. And you say it belongs in a sacred symbol of Jesus' blood? This practice came into the church the same way other things came into the church that were not meant to be.The Word of God, history, and even common sense tells you that fermented wine is vile,but you still hold to your traditions? In the words of the Almighty, "BUT IN VAIN DO THEY WORSHIP ME, TEACHING AS DOCTRINES THE PRECEPTS OF MEN. Neglecting the commandment of God, you hold to the tradition of men." Mark 7:7-8. We must prayerfully study this.

Comment: @jlaverde This tradition started in the 19th century and only in the U.S.A.  Yes, it is a tradition one that was developed independantly from teaching of the disciples as a result of the apostacy which seperated and continues to separate those who would be faithful to God. I am amazed how people cannot distinguish traditions based on cultures created independantly of all others and continue to and hold on to them. Men don't beat there wives because to wine, I drink wine often and never have the desire to hurt anyone especially the love of my life.  Evil comes from the heart, not the bottle.

Comment: @jlaverde Here is a link you can prayerfully wrestle with.http://www.catholic.com/magazine/articles/got-wine

Comment: @Marc this is an interesting link with some good texts on the subject. However, Dr. Bacchiocchi, has answered these misconceptions in his book. If you would like to move this to a chat, I could provide you with ample Biblical evidence of why Mr. Blackburn is incorrect in his interpretation. Let me know if you would like to study this further. You have your position which you believe is correct, as I have mine. However, the Bible has only one true interpretation, the one the Holy Spirit meant when He inspired people to write. If we seek it, we will find it, as is promised by our Lord Jesus.

Comment: @Marc I should also mention, I am not so blind as to believe that my interpretation of the Word is always right, and this is why I would like to invite you to study this point by point in a chat, if you would like.

Comment: I would be plaesed to. However, I am new and have never started one.  Please start one and I will check in when I return from work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22934/discussion-between-jlaverde-and-marc).

Comment: You've received down votes here because you're just giving your own view. This site requires that you represent views of Christian groups. You have two sources that may well meet this criteria, but they are presented as "learn more". This answer should read more like "Some groups, such as [name a few], believe ... Here's two sources." Most of the rest of this would fit on the question "What is the biblical basis for [this view]?"

Comment: This question is asking for *Baptist* and other *denominational* views. Can you please [edit] this to add evidence of a denomination holding this perspective.

Comment: @curiousdannii Sure. No problem.

Comment: @jlaverde, in Deuteronomy 14:22-29, God gave explicit permission for fermented drink to be part of the feast associated with bringing tithes of crops & livestock to the tabernacle.  Verses 26 reads:  "And thou shalt bestow that money for whatsoever thy soul lusteth after, for oxen, or for sheep, or **for wine, or for strong drink,** or for whatsoever thy soul desireth: and thou shalt eat there before the Lord thy God, and thou shalt rejoice, thou, and thine household."